# Could we have a silver badge for 100 accepted answers?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badge-request

We'd be counting the number of one's answers which are accepted. The number (100) requisite for the badge could easily be fudged; it's not crucial to the idea.  I think this badge would *a)*. encourage only good behavior, namely producing good and *accept*-able answers, and *b).* not be too redundant.  It should probably be able to be awarded multiple times, and could be gold instead.

I'm curious to know what you all think.

Comment: If you get downvoted on meta it's because they disagree with the idea, not because they don't like you.  +1

Comment: Good[.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/101118/164012)

Comment: How about if we're tired of people who come on Meta and whine about downvotes? What should we do then? If we tell you to be quiet about *that*, will you? Not only is this in the FAQ, it's blindingly intuitive that feature requests should be downvoted to indicate disagreement. So -1 from me for A) whining about downvotes and B) for a badge proposal that's redundant with rep gain.

Comment: @CodyGray It's not blindingly intuitive, it's a peculiar tradition. On SE2.0 metas, it often comes up as a WTF: “if I'm against it, I'll post/upvote an answer saying ‘no’, why would I downvote the question?”.

Comment: @Gilles: Yes, there's an irrational fear of downvoting other people's posts. It comes from an irrational fear of having one's *own* posts downvoted. I don't understand either.

Comment: @CodyGray That's not related to a fear of downvoting. Many SE users genuinely do not know that downvotes mean something different on Meta, and don't have the idea to read the FAQ because they've already read the one on the main site and don't even suspect that this aspect might be different.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Accepted answers are already rewarded: you get +15 rep for each one. So 100 accepts got you 1.5K rep.

The accepted rep is gained even if you've hit the rep cap.

There are badges like `Enlightened` (and `Unsung hero`) that are also related to accepted answers.

So in my opinion, there are already enough rewards in place for this.

Comment: Not sure how the question got -9 and this only got +1. Surely this is the exact reason everyone opposes the badge. It certainly sums up *my* objections.

Comment: reason I declined this ...

Answer (score 1):

I support the suggestion for this badge type, because the issue with reputation is that you can accumulate a reasonable level of reputation by asking lots of questions that get up voted, while making little effort to answer questions. Obviously, the site needs both questions and answers, but it would be valuable to have a more targeted reinforcement in place to produce answers, that was lower-hanging fruit than the Specialist badge, and rewarded a quantity of (accepted) answering even if it was not all on the one tag.