# Gold Sportsmanship badge

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request

I propose a new Gold level Sportsmanship badge.  I earned the silver badge June 4th, and I continue to vote for competing answers.  I would like to feel that I am working toward something, not because I would otherwise cease to vote for these answers, which clearly I have not, but because it adds to the fun of the site, just like the other badges.

Following the ratios of some other badges, since the silver is at 100, perhaps 400 votes for competing answers is a good level?

---

When I asked this question I was unaware that all votes for competing answers were counted, believing it was limited to the number of questions.  Since in fact all votes are counted I think the threshold needs to be higher, perhaps 1000 votes as suggested by **user unknown**.

---

This feature request is fairly popular but has failed to reach critical mass.  If anyone has new ideas about how this request might be changed to make it more likely to succeed please share them.

---

#### May 2016

There is renewed interest in this topic due to a similar request on Meta Stack Overflow (as well as a generous bounty just started by [Josh Crozier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/232567/josh-crozier)):

- [Needs More Sportsmanship](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323487/618728)

The community should at least be aware of this parallel development.  Perhaps that question should be migrated here and combined with this one as I believe badges are network-wide?  Any missing or controversial aspects of this question could be edited appropriately.

Comment: Yes, but what would you call it?  Super-Duper Sportsmanship?  :-)

Comment: @LarsTech I have not given that consideration.  I suppose "Gold Sportsmanship" would be redundant, but not exactly confusing.  One could also go for something like "Enduring Sportsmanship" but that appears to speak more of time than volume, which doesn't match my proposal.

Comment: Would the [Lady Byng](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lady_Byng_Memorial_Trophy) badge be too obscure a reference?

Comment: @Bill I don't know.  I had to follow the link to learn the meaning, but I hope that most on this site are not opposed to learning.  It would feel funny for some reason to have Lady something on my profile. :^)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It was worth a shot.  A lot of hockey fans would have to follow the link too.  :)

Comment: @BilltheLizard: +1 Exactly what I was going to suggest.

Comment: How about `Olympian` as a badge name?

Comment: Having `Olympian` as a badge name is likely to get you yelled at by the IOC.

Comment: As a word that is hundreds of years old, I don't think the IOC can lay claim to `Olympian`. However, I don't know that it conveys the correct meaning that well. I tend to think of "god-like" in some aspect or another when I read "Olympian" outside the realm of the games.

Comment: Do not want. But if we get this, can we also get a Gold "PHD" badge for *downvoting* competing answers.

Comment: Any particular reason you don't like this, @AnthonyPegram ? I mean, apart from the obvious fallout of friendly upvoting destroying all of stackexchange.

Comment: @jball, I might be alone, but we don't need badges for *everything*, and behavior-encouraging badges should ultimately benefit the site in terms of adding useful content, generating views, etc. A silver badge for a benevolent yet ultimately lesser activity such as this is sufficient, in my view.

Comment: I suggest the levels be at par with other badges (e.g. 100 and 500). For reference: S&W/CopyEditor: 80/500 Deputy/Marshal: 80/500 Electorate: 600

Comment: Say this is implemented. What happens after you earn this badge? Will you want a new level of platinum badges to be created to further "add to the fun"? Where does it end? I don't see any benefit to the community from this, and it would further clutter up an already-noisy badge page.

Comment: @jball this is getting off topic, but history has shown that not having total dominion over the word "Olympian" doesn't stop the IOC from yelling.

Comment: @PopularDemand What happens *after*?  The same thing we do every night, Pinky...

Comment: Same request on Meta SO: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323487/needs-more-sportsmanship

Answer (score 111):

First of all, I second the request.

As for the name:

Since upvoting a tremendous amount of competing answers implies that the user actually cares about the question getting answered instead of just wanting to "score" himself, I suggest **Team player**.

Comment: `himself` is politically incorrect!

Comment: @bestsss: So am I.

Comment: you mean 'team player' or politically incorrect (if the latter, it's very politically incorrect to say so, mind you)

Comment: @bestsss: Talking about a generic user (not one in particular) is gender neutral and perfectly good English. The context makes clear that it does not necessarily refer to a *male* user.

Comment: "themself" using the singular-they instead of "himself" would be gender neutral without feeling forced

Comment: @RichardTingle `singular-they` is a linguistic abomination. On the other hand, "team player" is a good name for this badge.

Comment: @Floris Any particular reason for that? It has a long pedigree including authors such as Jane Austin. Not to mention being incredibly useful (which ultimately should be the barometer of the language)

Comment: @richardtingle maybe it's just the way Facebook and others use "they": "it's John's birthday. Write something on their wall." - it makes me cringe! I am sure that FB has figured out the gender of their members. I believe that "he" can be used in a gender neutral sense, and that is my preference. To me, PC means personal choice.

Comment: @Floris, yes that is idiotic. Singular they should only ever be used for an uncertain or generic person. I have however never understood how "he" could ever include someone female. It's not me being PC, it's that that word explicitly refers to a male person (worse still how would you refer to a generic male person? Now that "he" has been stolen for a generic male or female person). Regardless I feel we have diametrically opposed views on this and I don't want to get into an off topic debate

Comment: The word doesn't explicitly refer to a male; similarly, man refers to both men and women. This has been the case for a very very long time - it is only relatively recently that various movements have objected vocally to this.

Answer (score 52):

I like [Corinthian spirit](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Corinthian_spirit), but I think this is very much a British English-only phrase.

Comment: +1 for a British English phrase---definitely a feature, not a bug. :-D

Comment: I'd never heard the phrase before reading this, but that gives it an air of mystery that suits a gold badge.

Answer (score 30):

I like it!!

How about "Not a rep Monster"?

Or, "Not A Rep Whore"

I wanted to design a badge for it but got bored and completely redesigned the gold badges.

[image]

(Note that the 1000 is random, I prefer 400/500)

Comment: Before anyone says "not enough jquery": I used jQuery+contentEditable to do this.

Comment: Nice. Now how does this add constructively to the conversation? I'm hoping to see this actually implemented. You're playing with JQuery.

Comment: This would have been perfect two days ago...

Comment: @TimPost: Well, I wanted to design a badge-image for it, just 'cos badges look cool. And then I got a little carried away--the relevant badge is still there, just with a whole lot of other stuff. :/

Comment: So the "constructive" part is the badge name and image, The rest is noise, I guess. Didn't want my jQuery to go to waste ;)

Comment: Well, jQuery is never wrong. Who knows what could happen? :P

Comment: "Self explanatory"? No, you've got some 'splaining to do.

Comment: I think the JonSkeet badge should go to the user with the highest rep - an honorary badge, in the spirit of the emergent culture of the community. Also, let's face it - we know Jon Skeet's never going to lose the badge until he dies (even then, his existing posts might just be self sustaining enough to farm enough rep in auto-pilot mode)

Comment: I don't think "Not a rep monster" is a good idea because we don't just want to post to earn rep. So, I propose "Competer".

Answer (score 24):

I'd call the badge "Spirit". The spirit of the site is to get all good content up to the top where it can be as useful as possible.

If you consistently up vote based on *merit* alone, even if it means another answer scores higher than your own, then you have the spirit of the site at heart.

And yes, I think that does deserve a gold badge. By the time someone reached ~400 - 500 votes, it means we're just rewarding someone again for consistent, desirable behavior. That's precisely what badges should be doing.

Comment: Thanks for your support.  Do you specifically favor "Spirit" over "Corinthian Spirit" (my favorite suggestion)?

Comment: I think either would be quite nice. I do favor "Spirit" but I'm at a bit of a loss to articulate why. I think I'd be at the same loss to explain why I like one color over another. In any event, I really hope to see it implemented. The idea sounds great to me, I hope the hardest part is deciding on the name :)

Answer (score 11):

I vote for it to be called Esprit de Corps :-)

Answer (score 10):

In the spirit of terms like "Fair play", the ideas of ethics and friendly competition embodied in "Sportsmanship", and just plain fun, I propose that the badge be called **Good Game**.

Comment: I was of the impression that `good game` has lost its original meaning in some circles and could carry with it a shade of sarcasm.

Comment: It depends on the context and the tone used. Just like "great" can be used for "really good" and "not good at all". I think attaching the term to a gold badge would make the intention clear, but it could be a little muddy.

Answer (score 9):

I quite like "Gentlemanly Conduct" as a name - again possibly a little British, but my other suggestion, "Jolly Good Show!", might have been a little over the top.

Gentlemanly Conduct does capture the spirit of fair play and sportsmanship in a nice phrase.

Comment: Is there a more sex agnostic code of conduct? Maybe "Chivalry" would be the way to go?

Comment: Chivalry is a nice way of putting it. Not as much fun, but gets the message over.

Answer (score 8):

I second the request, but would suggest a higher threshold, like 1000 votes.

Answer (score 6):

What about "Olympic Spirit"?

[image: those should be five free hand circles]

Inspired by the answers from [AakashM](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116748/155982) and [Tim Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127950/155982).

Comment: Maybe it should be a medal instead of a badge.

Comment: Not an option, the Olympic folks are [way too protective of their trademarks](http://www.olympic.org/legal-information/documents-reports-studies-publications). It is almost ridiculous, news agencies have trouble covering the games legally.

Answer (score 6):

I really do like the incentive to vote for competing answers,

but maybe this badge is a little bit more easy to grind at than a gold badge ought to be.

---

There's also the room people to avoid the incentive by up-voting on questions that are weeks or months old(thus not putting their own answer in jeopardy).  You might want to put some sort of time-limit on this, or only count votes that occur before the OP has accepted an answer.

Comment: That's probably over-thinking it a bit. Assuming we want a gold badge for this, where's the harm in older answers getting votes?

Comment: @AnnaLear  Well, for one, badge grinders are going to go down their list of answers, and indiscriminately up-vote every other answer in those questions, regardless whether they're good answers or not.

Comment: Sam, since a Gold badge should be fairly hard to get I'm not opposed to your proposed time restriction, but if such a restriction would result in this badge not being implemented due to the additional hassle I'd rather see the badge implemented anyway, without it.

Comment: Another possible restriction would be that your own answers each have to have a minimum score, so you cannot simply post a pile of marginal answers and upvote everything else.  What do you think of that?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  Well, if the restriction was on the answers you've upvoted, rather than the answers you've posted, that would solve the grinding issue

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  The badge description is "Up voted 100 answers on questions **where an answer of yours has a positive score**" posting an answer with a positive score might not be difficult, but it's difficult enough that you can't just repeat it on demand.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think the confusion comes from your own idea having already been implemented

Comment: +1 For "only count votes that occur before the OP has accepted an answer." that definitely requires more sportsmanship. Even more so if you upvote a competing answer above your own!

Answer (score 3):

I would go with:

> Up voted 400 answers on questions where an answer of yours has a score of 3 or more

Adding the requirement to have 3+ score on your own answer is the key and wasn't suggested before as far as I can see, and it would both make it harder to gain and harder to game.

Leaving the name choosing to others. :)

Comment: Please say more about harder to game.  If I had an answer with 3 upvotes, couldn't I just upvote all other answers which have 0 or 1 upvotes regardless of their true usefulness ... and still be ahead of them?

Comment: @HansUp but it's not easy to get the 3 upvotes. Maybe it's just harder to gain, hmm...

Comment: Thinking about this more, the harder to gain is really my concern.  My answers are in the ms-access tag family, where it's rare to get 3 upvotes.  So I got no reasonable chance of ever getting the "Golden Spirit of SO" (or whatever it's called) badge.  Which is too bad, because that's one of the few I would actually care much about.  Whether or not I can ever get one, I like the proposal ... and that is still true if your 3 vote requirement is adopted.  I'll just curse you privately.  :-0

Comment: Well, gold badge should never be easy to get and requiring just more answers to upvote, even 1000, doesn't sound enough to me.

Comment: Difficult <> impossible.  But I can't argue you're wrong.  If I want that thing badly enough, I can start posting in tags where votes aren't so hard to get.  But I still may curse you anyway.  Cheers.

Comment: I like this idea, at least on the surface. +1  @HansUp Unfortunately some badges just don't work form some sites/communities -- I'd love the Generalist badge but at present it is *impossible* on [Mathematica.SE].  Likewise the Unsung Hero is pretty much *never* going to happen as at [Mathematica.SE] people actually vote for good answers (imagine that).  I'm sorry to hear of your troubles but quite honestly if its hard to get three votes on a good answer in the `ms-access` tag there is something *wrong* with that community.

Comment: Another possibility for making this harder to gain and especially game would be only counting a maximum of *n* competing up-votes for each question; this would prevent someone from simply up-voting *every* answer in a popular thread.  Values for *n* might be 1 to 3.

Answer (score 1):

Good sportsmanship doesn't require badges. If you are upvoting others' posts, you are not doing it for money, fortune, or stinkin' badges. You simply do what you feel is right.

To be rewarded for this by others on StackExchange seems as incongruous as being rewarded for something **right** in real life.

Comment: So what you actually say that we're better off without any badges.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - I don't **care** much about them, least of all for upvoting others. There may be others who do, though. But to issue badges for decent behavior is kind of weird, to my mind.

Comment: OK, let's agree to disagree then. :)

Comment: The bronze level of this would serve more as an "Oh, that's something especially encouraged" (like getting a badge for figuring out that you can open your inventory in some games). Bronze badges are more of a just-in-time 'yay you did something good' signal than a reward, often triggering at the first instance of you doing it. And you do get rewarded for doing stuff right in real life. Has no one ever said "Good job"?

Answer (score -2):

I am not going to discus the name nor the number of votes necesary for such badge, just going to quote the Tour:

> Good answers are voted up and rise to the top.

If this is really what we want, such badge will be useful, as it would motivate even people with upvoted answers vote for other good answers.

Comment: Probably because the answer is about the badge in general, while the request is about "upgrading" the silver to gold, so the answer doesn't really fit in that context.

Comment: How do you know that it will motivate users to vote only for good answers and not just to upvote all answers to get some silly badge?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz But then we need to also remove the silver badge. And if you think that such badge motivates just voting for a badge there are even more voting badges which should be removed.

Comment: @convert I wouldn't mind removing all badges - and also reputation if we are at it

Comment: @sam sure, and make SE just a lame site not better a bit than the other Q&A sites.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz To be honest I wouldn´t mined, but this would change the complete concept of SE, which makes it uniqe, at least as far I know.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard Chasing Stars "Upgrading"? I was thinking it´s about adding a new badge similar to some other mentioned "families" of silver/gold badges.

Comment: @convert yeah, I mean adding upgraded version of same badge, while keeping the silver as well.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard Chasing Stars Then I don´t see the disagreement? The new badge should motivate you to upvote good answers even after earning the silver one.